# error in attribute routing MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to route action with multiple optional parameters but it is not working. I'm sharing my code please guide me.

```
[HandleError]
[RouteArea("Admin", AreaPrefix = "sp-admin")]
[RoutePrefix("abc-system")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class AbcController : Controller
{
   [Route("list/{id:int?}/{PersonID?}/{ref?}")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id, int? PersonID, string @ref)
   {
      return view();
   }
}
```

This will not work like this
http://anylocallink.com/sp-admin/abc-system/list/2/details
but work like this
http://anylocallink.com/sp-admin/abc-system/list/2/3/details

i want it to work if link has any of the optional parameter.
Please guide me

Comment: How is the route supposed to know you want "2" in id versus personID? This simply can't be done.

Comment: @Shoe is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because the route won't know where to put the `int` parameter. You could do something like this though

```
[Route("list/{type}/{id}/{ref?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string type, int id, string @ref)
{ 
    if(type == "Person"){ ... }
    else { ... }

   return View();
}
```

Then you can do this for a route

```
list/Person/1/Details
list/ID/2/Details
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify 'alpha' as the constraint for the @ref action parameter and have two actions like following:

```
[Route("list/{id:int?}/{ref:alpha?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id, string @ref)
{
  return await Index(id, null, @ref);
}

[Route("list/{id:int?}/{personId:int?}/{ref:alpha?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? id, int? personId, string @ref)
{
  return View();
}
```

This does work for both the scenarios. I prefer this because I do not have to
modify my routes again and again.

Comment: can you try this
https://viraj_siriwardana@bitbucket.org/viraj_siriwardana/routeattributingquiz-25655735.git

Comment: Or else you can add the two routes into the same action. But I think you should revise your action method design rather than trying to put all options in one.